# Integral of $t^2e^{it^2}$

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

Is it allowed to solve this integral:

$${I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{t^2e}^{it^2}dt}$$

as follows?

$$I=\lim_{a\rightarrow1}{\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{t^2e}^{iat^2}dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{-i\frac{\partial e^{iat^2}}{\partial a}}dt=-i\frac{d}{da}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{iat^2}dt\right]}\\
=\lim_{a\rightarrow1}{\left[i\frac{d\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2a}}\right)}{da}\left(1+i\right)=i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\left(2a\right)^3}}\left(1+i\right)\right]}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}(i-1)$$

Comment: You have an integral that depends on $a$, but then you calculate the limit as $a \rightarrow 1$. So, what is the actual problem you are solving?

Comment: Edited, the integral function is as in the title

Comment: If it converges, the integral is related to the Fresnel functions. Beware that your integration ranges should be $-a\to a$.

Comment: In your development, the key point is the interchange of the integral with the derivative. Check the conditions of the Leibnitz rule.

Comment: So inverting derivation and integration is in this case illegal because $e^{iat^2} t^2$ is not bounded in the integration interval, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Your integral diverges.  Integrate by parts to get an antiderivative
$$
\int_0^x t^2 e^{it^2} dt = \frac{-ixe^{ix^2}}{2} + \frac{i\sqrt{\pi}}{2(\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2})}\;\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2}}{2}\;x\right)
$$
But then note $\int_0^x t^2 e^{it^2} dt$ converges neither as $x \to +\infty$
nor as $x \to -\infty$.  Here is its real part:
[image: real part]

Note that the "principal value" $\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{-x}^x t^2 e^{it^2} dt
=2\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{0}^x t^2 e^{it^2} dt$ also diverges.

Comment: I asked why the integral could not be  solved by parameter differentiation and the answer is that Leibniz rule can't be applied in this case because the integration range is infinite and the derivative unbounded in it.